# Android ignores language if it is set as secondary

Tags: android, android-resources, android-locale

I have an app that supports German (de) and French (fr). German should be the default language.

the files are called:

- values/strings.xml <- German
- values-fr/strings.xml <- French

I already added in the build.gradle `resConfigs "fr"`

- When I set French as my primary language, the app appears in French.
- When I set German as my primary language, the app appears in German.
- When I set English as my primary language, the app appears in German.

All these cases work as expected.

But when I set English as my primary language, and French as the secondary language, the App still appears in German. In my opinion Android should display the App in French instead of German. Can someone explain to me why the behavior is somewhat non-intuitive or if I made a mistake somehow?

Android 12.0, SDK 33